What is the minhag for a secular couple who become Baalei Teshuvah
According to Halacha, minhag of a married couple follows the husband. What is the Halacha about the minhag for a secular married couple who become Baalei Teshuvah later on? What about a religious woman who marriages a secular man who later becomes a Baal Teshuvah?

If he has minhagim, what's your question? If he doesn't have minhagim, what's your question?

Why do you assume it shouldn't be something other than ye obvious of whatever the minhagim the husband adopts?

If they become baalei tshuva together, the most likely scenario is that they do it with the same Rav/community, and therefore adopt its minhagim. A religious woman who marries a man with no minhagim keeps hers, if he later becomes religious, they will decide together with their Rav what to do.

@mbloch in the latter case, R' Hershel Schachter paskens that she has a community and he doesn't, so he effectively has moved into her community and is expected to take on her community's customs. (The same applies if he became BT one year ago, by the way.)
